# Cross Domain application Page display via post call

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

We have one issue in displaying other domain page in our application.
*Here is the Issue*: Consider applications NS and TPT, I need to display application TPT page in application NS and I need to pass sensitive data to From NS to TPT.

When I tried to get complete page from TPT and display in NS, I don't see data in browser though i see complete page through view-source (Because of Same Origin Policy).

Is there anyway I can get this done by overcoming 'Same Origin Policy'?

Here is the code I used from NS:

```
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost:8090/tpt-web/jas/dashboard/home.action",
            type : "POST",
            cache : false,
            data : "USER:raj",
            dataType : "text",
            success : function(result) {
                var newWindow = window.open("http://localhost:8090/tpt-web/jas/dashboard/home.action", "", "height=815,width=680,top=0,right=250,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizeable=no");
                newWindow.document.write(result)
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error occured while connecting to TPT application');
            }
        });
```

Comment: is TPT application yours?,do you have control over TPT application

Comment: Yes I do have complete control over both the applications.

Comment: Then ofcourse you can give the access for cross domain . which  is your server side script

Comment: How can I give access from server side script, Can you give one example of such?

Comment: Which server side script are u using

Comment: I'm not using any script as such on server side... I'm using Spring MVC.